# How to run a javascript based on the results of a php if statement

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, if-statement

Ok when I test your solution on its own it works perfectly but as part of the complete code it still doesn't work. At first is was running without the prompt box appearing and when trying certain solutions it says I am receiving an expected expression error on the first line. Can anybody help solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

```
    <?php      
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];   
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$housenum = $_POST['housenumber'];
$contactnum = $_POST['contactnumber'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$county = $_POST['county'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$repeatpassword = $_POST['passwordrepeat'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$uniid = $_POST['uniid'];
$usertype = $_POST['usertype'];

if ($password == $repeatpassword) {
    if (strlen("$password") >= 8)   {
        // when all tests are run queries etc can replace these comments.
        if (strlen("$postcode") >= 6 && strlen("$postcode") <= 7)   {
            if (strlen("$uniid") == 9)   {
                if (strlen("$firstname") != 0 && strlen("$surname") != 0)   {
                    if (strlen("$email") != 0)  {
                        if (strlen ("$city") != 0)  {
                            if (strlen ("$county") != 0)    {
                                if (strlen("$contactnum") == 11)    {
                                    // collects input from user from the signup form using $_POST method.
                                    // inserts data into the respective column in table userinfo in the mysql database systemone.
                                    // connect to database

                                    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","123paulrivers","systemone");

                                    // Check connection

                                    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                                    {

                                    // if connection to database fails. States error.

                                        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                                    }
                                    if ($usertype == "Administration")  {
                                ?>
                                <body onLoad = "promptMessage();">    
                                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                                            function promptMessage() {

                                                var x = 38773;

                                                var code = prompt('Enter the administration code you have been given:', 'Enter code here');

                                                    if (code == x) {
                                                        alert('Admin code accepted');
                                                    } else {
                                                        prompt('The code you hae entered is inccorect', 'Enter code here or change Usertype');
                                                        }
                                        }   
                                       </script>
                                 </body>
                                 <?php

                                 }

                                     $sql="INSERT INTO completeinfo (FirstName, Surname, UniID, HouseNumber, AddressLineOne, AddressLineTwo, City, PostCode, County, PhoneNumber, Email, Username, Password, UserType)
                                     VALUES
                                     ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[surname]','$_POST[uniid]','$_POST[housenumber]','$_POST[addresslineone]','$_POST[addresslinetwo]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[postcode]','$_POST[county]','$_POST[contactnumber]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[usertype]')";

                                     if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))   {
                                       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                                       }   
                                       else  {

                                    // collects input from user from the signup form using $_POST method.
                                    // inserts data into the respective column in table account in the mysql database systemone.
                                    // SHA1 is an encryption for all passwords entered to improve security.

                                    // states if there was an error or record was added successfully.

                                    // add if clause checking to see the user type if pg perform $postgrad, if lecturer perform $lecturer. 

                                    if ($usertype == "Post Graduate")   {
                                    $postgrad = "INSERT INTO postgraduate (FirstName, Surname, UniID, Username) SELECT Firstname, Surname, UniID, Username FROM completeinfo WHERE UserType = 'Post Graduate'";
                                    if (!mysqli_query($con,$postgrad))   {
                                       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                                       }   
                                       else  {
                                        header("Location:SignUpComplete.html");
                                       }
                                    }

                                            if ($usertype == "Lecturer")    {
                                            $lecturer = "INSERT INTO lecturer (FirstName, Surname, UniID, Username) SELECT Firstname, Surname, UniID, Username FROM completeinfo WHERE UserType = 'Lecturer'";
                                            if (!mysqli_query($con,$lecturer))   {
                                       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                                       }   
                                       else  {
                                            header("Location:SignUpComplete.html");
                                            }
                                        }    
                                       }
                                    header("Location:SignUpComplete.html");    

                                } else  {
                                    header("Location:ContactNumberFail.html");
                                }
                            } else  {
                                header("Location:CountyFail.html");
                            }    
                        } else  {
                            header("Location:CityFail.html");
                        }     
                    } else  {
                        header("Location:EmailFail.html");
                    }                         
                } else  {
                    header("Location:NameFail.html");   
                }
            } else  {
                header("Location:UniIDFail.html");
            }
        } else    {
            header("Location:PostCodeFail.html");
        }
    } else  {
        header("Location:PasswordLengthFail.html");
     }
} else    {
        header("Location:PasswordMatchFail.html");
    }

    ?>
```

Above is the PHP and below is the HTML form which sends the information to the PHP.

```
    <body>
     <!--Form sends information entered by the user to userinfo.php
        for processing. Each name value is the variable which is called
        in the php doc.-->
    <form action="StoreUserInfo.php" method="post">
        User Type: <select name="usertype">
                       <option>Lecturer</option>
                       <option>Post Graduate</option>
                       <option>Administration</option>
                   </select><br />
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"/><br />
        Surname: <input type="text" name="surname"/><br />
        Uni ID: <input type="number" name="uniid" /><br />
        House Number: <input type="number" name="housenumber"/><br />
        Address Line One: <input type="text" name="addresslineone"/><br />
        Address Line Two: <input type="text" name="addresslinetwo"/><br />
        City: <input type="text" name="city"/><br />
        Post Code: <input type="text" name="postcode"/><br />
        County: <input type="text" name="county"/><br />
        Contact Number: <input type="number" name="contactnumber"/><br />
        Email: <input type="email" name="email"/><br />
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
        Re-enter Password: <input type="password" name="passwordrepeat" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: You're missing the semicolons in your JS. Also missing quotes around your onLoad event (which you should not bind via an attribute anyway).

Comment: just because you're using `mysqli_`, it doesn't mean you're safe from trivial SQL injection attacks. Use prepared statements that `mysqli_` provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- missing quotations

  `<body onLoad = "promptMessage();">`

Here's the whole code reworked:

```
<?
if ($usertype == "Administration")  {
                                    ?>
                                    <body onLoad = "promptMessage();">    
                                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                                                function promptMessage() {

                                                    var x = 38773;

                                                    var code = prompt('Enter the administration code you have been given:', 'Enter code here');

                                                        if (code == x) {
                                                            alert('Admin code accepted');
                                                        } else {
                                                            prompt('The code you hae entered is inccorect', 'Enter code here or change Usertype');
                                                            }
                                            }   
                                           </script>
                                     </body>
```

you should end your javascript statements with a semicolon;
for eg:

```
`var x = 38773;`
```

and
loading javascript like you do:

```
<body onLoad = "promptMessage();">
```

is considered bad practice.

you may try consider using something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = promptMessage;
</script>
```

Comment: "you need to end the javascript statements with a semicolon" - mostly you don't. It is a good idea, but it's not technically necessary in most cases.

Comment: rephrased my answer to "you should"

Comment: "missing quotations" - since there's no space in the attribute, the quotes don't seem technically necessary either